# Logging Configuration Not Working for Akka

Tags: scala, logging, apache-kafka, akka, slf4j

I am having problems with configuration for logging with Akka. In my STDOUT it is not hiding them DEBUG messages. In my console I seeing this:

```
12:45:27.790 [example-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-18] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group1] Resuming partitions [test-topic-0]
12:45:27.823 [example-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-18] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=group1] Node 1001 sent an incremental fetch response for session 1829476633 with 0 response partition(s), 1 implied partition(s)
```

So I am needing to stop seeing DEBUG messages. I make my logging like this:

```
akka {

  # Loggers to register at boot time (akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger logs
  # to STDOUT)
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]

  # Log level used by the configured loggers (see "loggers") as soon
  # as they have been started; before that, see "stdout-loglevel"
  # Options: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  loglevel = "INFO"

  # Log level for the very basic logger activated during ActorSystem startup.
  # This logger prints the log messages to stdout (System.out).
  # Options: OFF, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  stdout-loglevel = "INFO"

}
```

And in my logback.xml I am writing this:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} level=[%level] marker=[%marker] logger=[%logger] akkaSource=[%X{akkaSource}]
                sourceActorSystem=[%X{sourceActorSystem}] sourceThread=[%X{sourceThread}] mdc=[ticket-#%X{ticketNumber}:
                %X{ticketDesc}] - msg=[%msg]%n----%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Why is not DEBUG messages being stopped?

My project structure

src -> main -> scala (here my source files in Scala)
src -> main -> scala -> resources (here my lokback.xml and appliction.conf)

Comment: Can you post your sbt project structure?

Comment: Yes I will post this

Comment: @M.K. I am posting my directories but I cannot post picture of them so I write arrows showing location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sbt project structure is incorrect. This should be the correct structure:

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
       <files to include in main jar here>
    scala/
       <main Scala sources>
    java/
       <main Java sources>
  test/
    resources
       <files to include in test jar here>
    scala/
       <test Scala sources>
    java/
       <test Java sources>
```

Then you also need to follow @Mario's advice as well of adjusting the logging at the package level.

Answer (score 1):

Log level can be configured [at package level](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#sample2), for example, adding the following to `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/>
```

sets the log level to `INFO` for all the components inside `org.apache.kafka` package, which should stop `DEBUG` messages.

Comment: I try your advices Mario but solutions is not working for me.

Comment: @Mojo post your project directory structure